# unable to delete hive table partition contains special character Equal sign(=)

Tags: hive, special-characters, hive-partitions

- inserted data in Hive table with partition column(CL) value as ('CL=18') which stored as /db/tbname/CL=CL%3D18 (invalid partition contains url encoded special character for equal sign).

  - As per [hortonworks community](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/5361/cannot-drop-corrupt-hive-partition-with-control-ch.html?childToView=224185#comment-224185) , it was mentioned hive stored special characters as url escaped.

    - I tried using escape sequence for equal sign as  \x3D(hex) , \u0030 (unicode) but  did not work

Ex: alter table tb drop partition (CL='CL\x3D18'); <-- did not work

Can some one help me,  am I doing some thing wrong for Equal(=) sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `alter table id  drop partition(cl="cl=18");` (or) by enclosing partition value with `single quotes(')` also.

i have recreated the scenario on end and **able** to **drop the partitions** with special characters without using any hex..etc sequence.

**Example:**

I have created partition table with cl as partition column `string`type.

```
hive> alter table t1 add partition(cl="cl=18"); --add the partition to the table
hive> show partitions t1; --list the partititons in the table
+-------------+--+
|  partition  |
+-------------+--+
| cl=cl%3D18  |
+-------------+--+
hive>  alter table t1  drop partition(cl='cl=18'); --drop the partition from the table.
hive>  show partitions t1; 
+------------+--+
| partition  |
+------------+--+
+------------+--+
```

Comment: Yea it worked. I tried same thing also earlier but did not work, I might have messed up some thing there. However thanks for your help!

Comment: drop partition name = $%7Bbizdate}, replaced by '${bizdate}'

Comment: Thank you!  I had multiple partitions, one with a `$`, so this worked for me--quoting just the partition with the special character: `drop partition (dt=20210416,hr=00,min='$min',site=newyork)`